How can I test a Sticker Pack App in Xcode 15?
I'm trying to create a stand-alone Sticker Pack App in Xcode 15.3. The project itself creates fine, I can add stickers to the project, I've set all of the many app icons, but when I run the project on either the simulator or my actual device, it opens the Messages app as expected, but the sticker pack does not show anywhere.
I can't find any solution to this, short of submitting the pack and hoping it actually works! Has support for this project type just been forgotten about by Apple, or is there something I've missed?

Eventually found a post suggesting it's a bug in Xcode 15.3 - downloaded 15.2 and it's working fine. Hopefully it will get fixed in the next release.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

It is still a problem in Xcode 15.4
